# Native UITextField Secure Text Entry forces English (US) keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a very simple login page (login + password).

My users are french, so their keyboard are French (azerty).

Since iOS 12, when they click on the password textfield, which is secured, the keyboard switches to English (qwerty), even if they do not have this keyboard installed on their devices. Moreover, if they do not have this keyboard installed, they can't switch back to their keyboard.

I found out that if I deactivate Secure Text Entry, the problem does not show up.

I also tried to set isSecureTextEntry programmatically, and the bug shows up.

I am adding two screenshots, one for each text field.

Thank you a lot for your time & help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have this problem too. It"s definitely an iOS 12 bug. Hopefully they fix it soon.

Comment: Thank you. I absolutely agree, but I can't find any other traces of this problem anywhere else, can you ?

Comment: Have you added the French keyboard from your device settings ?

Comment: French keyboard is my default keyboard as my iPhone is french and was initialized this way, so yes, it is installed :)

Comment: I currently have the same bug

Comment: Hello! I have the same issue, but with a weird behavior. I have a secure text field in the login view controller which is in AZERTY for french users and a secure text field in the signup view controller which is in QWERTY also for french users. It is kind of strange.

Comment: @imacode yes ! that's exactly my problem too. I have filled a bug report to Apple 45 days ago through Bug Reporter, no news at this point.

Comment: Solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004048/password-fields-keyboard-switches-from-azerty-to-qwerty-sometimes-only-on-ios/54749897#54749897

Comment: @ThibL Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was truly an iOS bug => corrected in iOS 12.1

Comment: we still have the problem on iOS 12.1

Comment: That's strange, we can't reproduce it anymore here

Comment: We also still have the problem on iOS 12.1.1

Comment: Still have the problem on iOS 12.1.2

Comment: Still have the problem on iOS 12.1.4

Comment: still there, iOS 12.2

Comment: still there in iOS 13+

Comment: still threre in iOS 14+

Answer (score 14):

I have the same issue, in my case this bug appears only with a register screen.

The reason is that Apple checks the name of the class/func/parameter to determine (with heuristics) if it is a login/register screen and activate automatically autofill password.
By replacing "register" with "Patate" in my code, the problem is solved.

I reproduce this issue with a sample app with 2 textfields (with a security text entry) and a view controller named "RegisterViewController". With a "PatateViewController", I have not the issue.

Moreover, I have this error in console :
[AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: *** due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled

Source : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill

Hope you will find a better way than renaming your code.

Comment: I'm upvoting it, "PatateViewController" is clearly the better name you can give to a ViewController 

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem appear recently on our application.
The problem is linked to the new feature of the **PasswordAutofill** from Apple.

To bypass this problem you can apply this little piece of code on your secure textfield

```
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        tfPassword.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
    }
```

This should resolve this bug.
This should also fix this error:

> [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: *** due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled

Ps: You could also add this new feature to your app.
This is a link to an article explaining the process on how to implement this new feature 
[Explanation on how to implement password autofill](https://medium.com/developerinsider/ios12-password-autofill-automatic-strong-password-and-security-code-autofill-6e7db8da1810)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This was the solution for me

Comment: When the user has its keychain disabled the bug still appears

Comment: Same in swiftUI, just add  .textContentType(.oneTimeCode).keyboardType(.default) to a SecureField

Answer (score 3):

Same solution in Swiftui now :

```
TextField("placeholder",text: $YourTextBinding)
                        .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
                        .keyboardType(.default)
```

just need to add :

```
                        .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
                        .keyboardType(.default)
```

to a `TextField` or a `SecureField`.

hope it helps !

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in React Native when I set the keyboardType to "numeric-pad". 
It's a native IOS issue due to default language set in `info.plist` file.

I found the solution here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27972

Delete these 2 lines to unset the default language :

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
```

You could also just modify `<string>en</string>` to `<string>fr</string>` but then you will have the same issue with english users who will have a switch to azerty keyboard :/

Comment: This is perfect solution.

Comment: Same problem on React Native but this doesn't fix it for me

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and solved it by setting **all** my textFields `textContentType` property to `UITextContentType.oneTimeCode`.

Of course, `oneTimeCode` is now useless since it's everywhere...

Comment: I am facing this issue...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495065/how-to-enable-disable-onetimecode-feature-for-specific-text-field

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:**

Create base class for UITextField with languageCode and textInputMode.

```
class BaseTextField: UITextField {

// ru, en, ....
var languageCode: String? {

    didSet{

        if self.isFirstResponder{

            self.resignFirstResponder();
            self.becomeFirstResponder();
        }
    }
}

override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode? {

    if let language_code = self.languageCode {

        for keyboard in UITextInputMode.activeInputModes {

            if let language = keyboard.primaryLanguage {

                let locale = Locale.init(identifier: language);
                if locale.languageCode == language_code {

                    return keyboard;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return super.textInputMode;
}}
```

**Usage:**

Set your value (ru, en, ...) to languageCode. It will force change the locale in the keyboard.

```
private func textConfigure(textField: UITextField) {

    textField.keyboardType = .default
    textField.autocapitalizationType = .words
    textField.languageCode = "ru"
}
```

Hope help you.

Comment: it doesn't work for keyboardType = .decimalPad, to display a dot or a comma

Answer (score 1):

iOS 12.1 fixed the problem for me.

You also have to set the parameter `textContentType` of the password textfield to `.oneTimeCode`

Comment: This does not fix the problem for my application. Running on iOS 12.1.2

Answer (score 1):

The lamer a bug is, the lamer the solution should be, i mean what a lame work by Apple.

My solution was to force a focus on the password field and then focus on the first field, in my case it was the usernameField.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [self.usernameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, I corrected this by simply adding this to my main viewController :

```
func passwordSignUpViewController(forAuthUI authUI: FUIAuth, email: String, requireDisplayName: Bool) -> FUIPasswordSignUpViewController {
    return CustomPasswordSignUpViewController(authUI: authUI, email: email, requireDisplayName: true)
}
```

And I created the subclass of FUIPasswordSignUpViewController

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseUI

class CustomPasswordSignUpViewController : FUIPasswordSignUpViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

 override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, authUI: FUIAuth, email: String?, requireDisplayName: Bool) {
    super.init(nibName: "FUIPasswordSignUpViewController", bundle: nibBundleOrNil, authUI: authUI, email: email, requireDisplayName: requireDisplayName)        
 }

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 }

 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        textField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, following line solve my problem.

`textField.textContentType = .newPassword`