# Keyboard layout changes from AZERTY to QWERTY for secure text field- SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios13.4

I'm having this weird bug where the keyboard layout changes from QWERTY to AZERTY only for the secure text fields and that too not for all textFields.
I have a LoginViewController which has a passwordField , its in AZERTY.
But the passwordFields on my SingUpViewController changes automatically from AZERTY to QWERTY.

```
if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    passwordField.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
}
```

It was previously an iOS 12 bug, which was fixed in iOS 12.1. 
I have also tried the solutions here [Native UITextField Secure Text Entry forces English (US) keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52701160/native-uitextfield-secure-text-entry-forces-english-us-keyboard) , but they don't work either.

Comment: What a fascinating bug! (What a useless comment. Bad matt.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53004048/password-fields-keyboard-switches-from-azerty-to-qwerty-sometimes-only-on-ios try these link

Comment: @vishnuanilkumar i have already tried that too, didn't solve for me.

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770550/set-a-passwordfield-to-securetextentry-give-me-a-strange-behaviour), if you have another textfield with the content-type `Email Address` on the same view, **changing its content-type to `Username`** (instead of `Email Address`) may fix the *qwerty* keyboard issue on your `Password` textfield.

Comment: No i don't have another field with content-type as Email Address.